# Creating colour schemes based on an existing scheme

Tags: color-palette

I have a colour scheme based around yellow, for warning messages on a website.  It amounts to a slightly orange bordered box, with a pale yellow fill.  The exact colours are:

- ## FED626 (border)
- ## FFF7C0 (fill)

I want to know if it's possible to convert this scheme mathematically or algorithmically somehow, to come up with a blue version where the border is the "same amount" of blue as this one is yellow.  Is this possible, or do I just "pin the tail on the donkey" on a colour pallet to get roughly the right one?

I ask, because I'd quite like to be able to calculate this on the fly, to perhaps implement something in [.less](http://www.dotlesscss.com/).

To give you an idea, I tried swopping the red and blue values on those two, and came up with this:

- ## 26D6FE (border)
- ## C0F7FF (fill)

That wasn't too hard, but think about if I wanted a pink colour scheme... :)

Comment: Okay okay, I know - spelling "colour" is just how I spell it - I'm on touch-typing autopilot. :)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Are you kidding me? I bet you say "Aluminum" too - and that's just a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just read part of the the [HSL and HSV page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and realise that all I need to do is pick a colour, then change the Hue value to rotate to a colour I want.

Easy, now I'm a graphics expert!